# Using multiple SQL databases

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I'm creating an Android app that will download XML data from my website, parsed xml data will be inserted into 5 separate SQL Lite tables. I have successfully logged into my website, got the XML data & parsed. **I not sure how to layout the database code for multiple tables**(opening, closing, inserting, selecting).

Also I would like (is this possible) these tables to stay on the device if the user needs to logout and come back to the app at a later time.

Any help or direction would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Do you simply need multiple tables within a single db (trivial functionality provided by SQL `create table` statement) or multiple databases (which sqlite will happily create for you if you pass `CREATE_IF_NECESSARY` flag to your `openDatabase()` method, given that you have permissions to create the file at the nominated location)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question title says "multiple databases", body says "multiple tables". I take it to mean "multiple tables".

Just use `SQLiteOpenHelper`. Create all the tables in `onCreate()`. Do the opening/closing and CRUD operations the same way you would do on a `SQLiteOpenHelper` hosting a single table.

Use a search engine to find tutorials about `SQLiteOpenHelper` in case you need them.